# Prove this function is lower semi-continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $B$ his borel $\sigma$-algebra. Fix $r>0$
Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(X,B)$ and define $f(x)=\mu(B(x,r))$.

Show that $f$ is lower semi continuous.

What I was thinking is that geometricly it is very obvious, but proving is harder. I think that inner-regularity (any probability measure on metric space is regular, right?) should be pretty usefull, but I can't seem to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am going to use the weak convergence of Radon measure.

Fix a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$, then we define
$$ \mu_n(X):= \mu(B(x_n,r))$$
You may verify that $\mu_n$ is a Radon measure and we have 
$$ \mu_n\to\mu $$
weakly in the sense of measure.

Then by properties of weak convergence of measure, we have, since $X$ is open, we have 
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(X)\geq \mu(B(x,r)) $$
which is the result we were looking for.

Comment: and yes, the properties I used here is bit over-killed... but I think it is good to know sth about properties of weak convergence of measure....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $x \in X$, $r>0$ and $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n \to x$. Then

$$1_{B(x,r)} \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} 1_{B(x_n,r)}.$$

(Indeed: If $y \in B(x,r)$, then $y \in B(x_n,r)$ for sufficiently large $n$ since $x_n \to x$.) Apply Fatous lemma:

$$\mu(B(x,r)) = \int 1_{B(x,r)}(y) \, \mu(dy) \leq \dots$$

Comment: wouldn't it simply prove $f(x)\leq \liminf \mu (B(x,r_n))$? It doesn't really help since the argument is $x$ and not $r$

Comment: @Merlin Ah, I'm sorry - I mixed it up. However, the argumentation works similar if $x$ is the argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you specify the definition of lower-semi-continuous you worked with here?

Comment: Or to be precise, what is the definition of liminf you used here

Comment: Well, it's the standard definition of liminf: $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf \{a_k; k \geq n\}$$ where $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence.